# Что такое монитор, мьютекс и семафор? Это одно и тоже или разные вещи?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Просто везде написано по-разному. И никак не могу понять, что по сути обозначает каждое из этих понятий. Например, у того же Эккеля есть такие строчки про это:

> Для решения проблемы соперничества потоков фактически все многопоточные схемы синхронизируют доступ к разделяемым ресурсам. Это означает, что доступ к разделяемому ресурсу в один момент времени может получить только один поток. Чаще всего это выполняется помещением фрагмента кода в секцию блокировки так, что одновременно пройти по этому фрагменту кода может только один поток. Поскольку такое предложение блокировки дает эффект взаимного исключения, этот механизм часто называют мьютексом (MUTual Exclusion).
>
> В Java есть встроенная поддержка для предотвращения конфликтов в виде
>   ключевого слова synchronized. Когда поток желает выполнить фрагмент
>   кода, охраняемый словом synchronized, он проверяет, доступен ли
>   семафор, получает доступ к семафору, выполняет код и освобождает
>   семафор.

Сам я читал в одной статье (и пока придерживаюсь этого понимания), что мьютекс - это некий объект, который связан с каждым объектом в Джава, и который может принимать два состояния: занят и свободен. А про монитор в той же статей было написано, что это некий специальный механизм (по сути - кусок кода), который, используя мьютекс, регулирует доступ нитей к некоторому блоку кода (то есть он отвечает за захват нити ресурса, и позволяет только одной данной нити (которая захватила мьютекс) идти по данному, охраняемому монитором, блоку кода; соответственно, другим нитям монитор не даёт занять этот ресурс и этот блок кода; а когда нить выходит из этого блока кода, то монитор освобождает мьютекс и позволяет другим нитям войти в этот блок кода). Это правильное понимание?

А что конкретно обозначают эти понятия в Джаве?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

В целом, можно считать, что мютекс это частный случай семафора. Семафор работает просто - у него есть некое начальное число - счетчик. Каждый раз, когда какой то поток "захватывает" семафор, это число уменьшается на единицу. Если оно равно нулю или меньше нуля - семафор запирается (то есть, грубо говоря, код останавливается на моменте захвата семафора). Каждый раз, когда семафор освобождается - этот счетчик увеличивается на единицу. И если он после этого окажется больше нуля, то какому то произвольному потоку, который "висит на захвате семафора" будет послан сигнал на пробуждение и он сможет продолжить работу (естественно, снова уменьшив значение счетчика).

Самый очевидный пример семафора - это менеджеры закачек - добавляем много файлов на закачку, но ограничиваем количество одновременных скачек.

А мютекс - это просто семафор, который инициализирован начальным числом 1. Поэтому, только один поток может его захватить. Но как всегда, есть исключения. Есть так называемые мютексы на чтение-запись (RWLock). Эти мютексы можно захватывать на чтение и на запись. И если на чтение может захватить много потоков, то на запись - только один (да, и в этот момент больше никто  не может читать).

> что мьютекс - это некий объект, который связан с каждым объектом в Джава, и который может принимать два состояния: занят и свободен.

это почти близко к истине. Да, в java у класса Object есть поле типа мютекс. И все наследники (читай все остальные классы) также получают персональный мютекс. если метод пометить словом syncronized, то это просто заворачивает его вызов в этот мютекс. То есть, если вызывать syncronized методы у одного объекта с разных потоков - мютекс не даст им выполнятся параллельно. Но для разных объектов (даже одного типа) это уже не работает.

Comment: Спасибо, довольно понятно объяснили. А что такое монитор?

Comment: монитор - это высокоуровневая штука, которая обычно работает на уровне компилятора (библиотеки) и скрывает от программиста явный вызов мютексов/семафоров. synchronized  в java - яркий пример.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо. Так и думал про монитор. Правда, во многих источниках монитором называется объект, по которому происходит синхронизация (например объект obj в блоке synchronized(obj) {}). От этого и путаница. Объект obj в блоке синхронизации - это мьютекс или монитор? или ни то, ни другое?

Comment: Мьютекс - это не просто семафор. Обычно мьютексы умеют детектировать рекурсивную блокировку, а системные в винде к тому же имеют защиту от смерти владеющего потока.

Comment: Да, как всегда есть исключения и особенности реализации.